# How to use curl command with data from a variable

Tags: json, linux, bash, rest, curl

I'm trying to make a script that execute a curl command to create a Rabbit Exchange with Rest API.

If I use --data with the definition like the follow:

```
HTTP_RESPONSE=$(curl --silent --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -u $USR:$PWD --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request PUT  --data '{"type": "topic","auto_delete": false,"durable": true,"internal": false,"arguments": {}}'  $URL_GENERATE_EXCHANGE)
```

It runs

But I want to pass the data from a variable like this

```
EXCHANGE_DEFINITION='{"type": "topic","auto_delete": false,"durable": true,"internal": false,"arguments": {}}'

HTTP_RESPONSE=$(curl --silent --write-out "HTTPSTATUS:%{http_code}" -u $USR:$PWD --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request PUT  --data  $EXCHANGE_DEFINITION $URL_GENERATE_EXCHANGE)
```

but It doesn't work...and I don't understand why....Can anyone help me please?

Thank you

Comment: When you say `It doesn't work` , what do you mean ? Do you get a `curl` error message ? Do you get an unexpected result ?

Comment: type `echo $EXCHANGE_DEFINITION`. You'll notice the simple quotes are note shown around your data. Try writting `" '$EXCHANGE_DEFINITION' "` instead.

Comment: Thank you @Aserre